# Is there a way to display a Solidity array of structs in React?

Tags: reactjs, solidity, smartcontracts

I am trying to display the contents of a Solidity array of structs in a React front-end.

This is my Solidity smart contract. I've created a function which returns the length of the array in question.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Project {

    struct Person {
        string name;
        string description;
    }
    
    Person[] public people;

    function getPersonCount() public view returns (uint) {
        return people.length;
    }

}
```

Here is my front-end React code:

```
import React from "react";
import Web3 from './web3';
import { ABI } from './ABI';
import { contractAddr } from './Address';

const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider);
const ContractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, contractAddr);

const NewPerson = () => {

    let personCount = 0;

    personCount = ContractInstance.methods.getPersonCount().call();

    return (
        personCount
    );
};

export default NewPerson;
```

When I run that front-end code, I get this error message:

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Reading answers to questions on here, I thought the problem might be that I need to call my Solidity function asynchronously so that I can return the output of the function rather than a promise. I tried re-writing my React code like so:

```
import React from "react";
import Web3 from './web3';
import { ABI } from './ABI';
import { contractAddr } from './Address';

const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider);
const ContractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, contractAddr);

const NewPerson = () => {

    let personCount = 0;

    async function handlePerson() {
        personCount = await ContractInstance.methods.getPersonCount().call();
    }

    handlePerson();

    return (
        personCount
    );
};

export default NewPerson;
```

This did not trigger an error, but instead returned 0 (suggesting that the handlePerson function did not even run).

I then tried another approach:

```
import React from "react";
import Web3 from './web3';
import { ABI } from './ABI';
import { contractAddr } from './Address';

const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider);
const ContractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, contractAddr);

const NewPerson = () => {


    let personCount = 0;

    async function handlePerson() {
        personCount = await ContractInstance.methods.getPersonCount().call();
        
        return (
            personCount
        );
    }
    return (
        handlePerson()
    );

};

export default NewPerson;
```

This gave me the same error message I got the first time around:

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

I'd be grateful if anyone has any advice to offer, or if anyone has experienced something similar. My goal is to then iterate through the array to display all of its elements, but so far I don't even seem to be able to display the number of elements in it. It's particularly strange since I'm successfully able to call other functions from my smart contract via the React front-end. Many thanks in advance!

### Update:

Many thanks to [MrFrenzoid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11269158/mrfrenzoid) for the help. I've re-written my front-end code so that I am now able to query individual elements of the Solidity array:

```
import React from "react";
import Web3 from './web3';
import { ABI } from './ABI';
import { contractAddr } from './Address';

const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider);
const ContractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, contractAddr);

const NewPerson = () => {
    
    // Using hard-coded personCount for testing purposes
    let personCount = 70;
    let people = [];

    async function handlePeople() {
        for (let i=0; i<personCount; i++) {
            const person = await ContractInstance.methods.people(i).call();
            people.push(person);
        }
        console.log(people);
    }

    handlePeople();

    return (
        null
    );

};

export default NewPerson;
```

This returns the contents of the array in the console, as expected.
The issue I'm still having is querying the length of the Solidity array, so that I can use that to compute personCount (rather than using a hard-coded value as I do above).

```
import React from "react";
import Web3 from './web3';
import { ABI } from './ABI';
import { contractAddr } from './Address';

const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider);
const ContractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, contractAddr);

const NewPerson = () => {

    let people = [];

    async function handlePersonCount() {
        const personCount = await ContractInstance.methods.getPersonCount().call();
        console.log(personCount);
    }

    async function handlePeople() {
        for (let i=0; i<personCount; i++) {
            const person = await ContractInstance.methods.people(i).call();
            people.push(person);
        }
        console.log(people);
    }

    handlePersonCount();
    handlePeople();

    return (
        null
    );

};

export default NewPerson;
```

When I run handlePersonCount(), I get this error message: [image: error message]

The reason I'm taking this approach at all is because I'm seemingly unable to query the entire Solidity array at once, and instead need to query one element at a time.

### Update:

Once I re-deployed the Truffle/Ganache instance in which I was running my local blockchain, I was able to invoke getPersonCount() from the front-end as expected. It seems my error was in not redeploying my local blockchain after creating a new function/variable in the smart contract.

Here is what my final, functioning front-end code looks like:

```
import React from "react";
import Web3 from './web3';
import { ABI } from './ABI';
import { contractAddr } from './Address';

const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider);
const ContractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, contractAddr);

const NewPerson = () => {

    let people = [];

    async function handlePersonCount() {
        const personCount = await ContractInstance.methods.getPersonCount().call();
        console.log(personCount);
        return(personCount);
    }

    async function handlePeople(qty) {
        for (let i=0; i<qty; i++) {
            const person = await ContractInstance.methods.people(i).call();
            people.push(person);
        }
        console.log(people);
    }

    async function handler() {
        await handlePeople(await handlePersonCount());
    }

    handler();

    return (
        null
    );

};

export default NewPerson;
```

I added the return line to handlePersonCount() so that I can feed handlePersonCount() into handlePeople() as a parameter, and then use the handler() function to force handlePeople() to wait until hanldePersonCount() has finished before being invoked. There's probably a cleaner way to set up that sequential functionality, but this seems to work.

Comment: In your second implementation, don't you think it returned 0 because youre printing the length of the array instead of its contents? Also, you can call your array using         const people = await ContractInstance.methods.people().call(); Also console log everything to check what youre getting. I'd also recommend using a state variable to not-render the component until you got the data from the contract, since the function youre calling is asyncronous.

Comment: This was really helpful. I used const people = await ContractInstance.methods.people().call(); plus a console log to see that I can in fact access elements of my array on the front-end. Now I'm just trying to figure out how to get array length so that I can iterate through the entire thing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In response to your last comment, since you already have the array in js, you can do a quick `people.length` you can also iterate over it using a normal for,

or an

```
people.foreach((person) => { console.log(person); });
```

or

```
for( const person in people){
   console.log(person);
}
```

If you have any issues let me know, attaching the error and your code below.

### Update 1 (How to grab a dynamic array with web3).

Try this:
Create a state variable which will hold your peoples array, make it an empty array when defined.

Then, do the following to iterate over each element, and stack them up.

```
// we create a local variable with the same name as the state variable where were going to hold our people elements.
let peopleArray = [];

// we query our counter.
const peopleCount = ContractInstance.methods.peopleCount().call();

// we iterate over each people and add it to our local variable.
// I start at 1 since in my contracts i first increment the counter
//   and then do else, since the contract calls aren't mutex, 
//   theres a chance for users to be able to trigger a "race condition" by
//   adding two "people" very fast, so fast that since the counter 
//   didn't update the first people was added, the second one will be 
//   processed with the same value as its counter, thats why, try
//   counting first, and then doing anything else, its a good practice! :D.

for (var i = 1; i <= peopleCount ; i++) {
        const person = ContractInstance.methods.people(i).call();
        console.log(person);
        peopleArray.push(person);
  }

// we set the local varible value as our state variable, since it has the same name, you dont need to do {peopleArray: peopleArray}
this.setState({peopleArray});
```

Your contract should look something like this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Project {

struct Person {
    string name;
    string description;
}

Person[] public people;
uint256 public peopleCount;

constructor(){
    peopleCount = 0;
}

function addPerson(string memory name, string memory description) public returns (Person memory) {
    // we do our corresponding checks.
    require(bytes(name).length > 0, "Error: Dont leave the name empty!");
    require(bytes(description).length > 0, "Error: Dont leave the description empty!");

    // We increment the counter first so we avoid a race condition
    peopleCount++;
    
    // Create a person
    Person memory p = Person(name, description);
    
    // Push the person
    people[peopleCount] = p;
    
    // return the created person.
    return p;
}
```

}

Remember that setting the storage variables (contract global variables such as  people and peopleCount) to public, will have solidity create getters for each variable implicitly, so if you have your variables on public, dont bother creating a getter unless you want something to do before returing said data, for example, tracking how many times people accessed to said variables .

Best regards!

Comment: Apologies, I should clarify. I wasn't able to use

`const people = await ContractInstance.methods.people().call();`

but rather

`const person = await ContractInstance.methods.people(id).call();`

to get a specific element (specified by id) from the Solidity array.

So I don't have the array itself in js, and am trying to query the length of the Solidity array so that I can iterate through each person and construct the array on the js side.

Comment: The reason I am querying one element at a time is because, when I try to get the entire array at once, I get this error: Unhandled Rejection (Error): Invalid number of parameters for "people". Got 0 expected 1!

I've tried [this approach](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3114/calling-public-array-of-structs-using-web3), but when I use my getter function to get the length of the Solidity array, I get an Internal JSON-RPC error with the message: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert.

Comment: Ahh i see, well after reading a bit the docs, it seems that you can't call directly a dynamic array, instead you have to create a counter in your solidity contract, and increment the counter each time you add a new element into the array, and iterate over it in web3 (oops, my bad :p). I've updated the answer with an example.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll give that a try. I thought that just taking the length of the array would work, but I'll try using a counter instead. Perhaps the fact that it is a dynamic array prevents me from using its length on the front-end.

Comment: Thank you for the additional example. This has been extremely helpful! I really appreciate your time.

Comment: Im updating the answer as time passes xD, sorry about it, its just that i remember things AFTER i've already submitted the answer.

Comment: @Kamil about whether you need a separate count variable, would a getter like this not work? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/20838 (I'm new to solidity, so not totally sure—but having to track a separate count variable would be super odd to me.) [Edit: Ah, sorry, I see you're already doing that! Reading your question more carefully...]

Comment: Yup that's what I tried first! I also just tried using a counter. Neither works for me (both give the same error, screenshotted in the update to my question). It's bizarre because I can get other public variables from my smart contract without issue -- it's just the counter and the count getter function that throw this error.

Comment: Wow... So I am testing this locally using Truffle/Ganache. I *think* the problem is that I didn't re-deploy Truffle/Ganache after creating getPersonCount() in my smart contract (even though I did update my ABI file). Once I shut down Ganache, and spun up a new local blockchain, I was able to invoke getPersonCount() from the front-end as expected. Thank you again for the help!

Comment: Ahhh damn, and i was complicating my life over it! Hahaha, well you learn something new everyday.

Comment: No no, its ok, its werid enough that you aren't able to call the implicit counter of the array. So its normal to find a workdaround.